# How is repastpy set up and started?

Tags: repast-simphony

My understanding is that repastpy is an environment that can be created from repast in which Python-like code is used to create agents, behaviors, etc. I would like to use repastpy because my Java knowledge is limited, but have been unable to figure out how to set up/start repastpy. How is repastpy set up and started?

I have repast-simphony 2.7 downloaded on my Mac as per https://repast.github.io/download.html, and I am able to get the Java version running from Eclipse - that is, for the repast window to open and start the Java-based examples (e.g., GeoZombies). In reviewing the repast simphony 2.7.0 folder in my Applications, I see several reference documents for getting started with batch or Java but not for Python.

I consulted the repastpy pages at http://repast.sourceforge.net/repast_3/repastpy/; they discuss how to use repastpy once started but not how to get repastpy set up and/or started in the first place (or, I have missed any such instructions).

I have also not seen a file name including "repastpy" anywhere through a search of my Mac after downloading and installing repast simphony.

I would appreciate any clarification anyone might be able to offer about how to get repastpy running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most current versions of Repast can be found here: https://repast.github.io
These include Repast Simphony and Repast HPC. Repastpy has been deprecated a while ago, so I would not recommend it as a way forward.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this all working by downloading the Repast_3.1_Suite_Installer.exe from https://sourceforge.net/projects/repast/files/Repast/Repast%203.1/ and then executing the installation. The default installation directory was c:/Program Files/Repast 3/. Inside this folder you can find the Repast Py folder which contains the RepastPy.exe launcher.

Best of Luck.